# Recode values using case_match() with a char array

Tags: r, dplyr, recode

In the **dplyr** package, `recode()` has been superseded in favor of `case_match()`. Is there a way to use labels stored in, for example, char array to recode values using `case_match()`?

For example, with `recode()` I can store labels in a char array (or read them from a CSV file) and use them for recoding:

```
lbls <- c(
    'male' = 'Man',
    'female' = 'Woman'
)

starwars %>%
    select( sex ) %>%
    mutate(
        sex = recode( sex, !!!lbls )
    )

# A tibble: 87 × 1
#   sex  
#   <chr>
# 1 Man  
# 2 none 
# 3 none 
# 4 Man  
# 5 Woman
# ...
```

However, since `case_match()` requires two-sided formulas (`old_values ~ new_value`), that does not work. Is there a way to use stored values also in `case_match()`?

Comment: *superseded* does not necessarily mean that it won't work in the near or distant future.

Comment: Ah, ok, so I can expect recode() to work in the foreseeable future? Sounds good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a set of rules to be evaluated.

#### `tidyverse` approach

As you're using `dplyr` let's go all in:

```r
(rules <- glue::glue('"{lbl}" ~ "{val}"', lbl = names(lbls), val = lbls))
# "male" ~ "Man"
# "female" ~ "Woman"
```

You can then turn this character vector into a list of `call` objects with [`rlang::parse_exprs()`](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/parse_expr.html). Then inject the list into the function call as arguments using the [splice operator](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/splice-operator.html), `!!!`:

```r
starwars |>
    select(sex) |>
    mutate(
        sex = case_match(
            sex,
            !!!rlang::parse_exprs(rules),
            .default = sex
        )
    )
# # A tibble: 87 × 1
#    sex  
#    <chr>
#  1 Man  
#  2 none 
#  3 none 
#  4 Man  
#  5 Woman
#  6 Man  
#  7 Woman
#  8 none 
#  9 Man  
# 10 Man  
# # ℹ 77 more rows
# # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

#### base R approach

We can also do the parsing and splicing in base R. For me it's a little clearer what's going on. We can define rules with `sprintf()` instead of `glue`, as suggested by Darren Tsai.

```r
rules <- c(
    "sex",
    sprintf('"%s" ~ "%s"', names(lbls), lbls)
)
```

To get the character vector into a list of language objects, instead of `parse_exprs()` we can use [`str2lang()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/parse.html). Then `!!!` is a way of applying `case_match()` to a list of arguments, i.e. the equivalent of [`do.call()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/do.call.html).

```r
starwars |>
    select(sex) |>
    mutate(
        sex = do.call(
            case_match,
            c(
                lapply(rules, str2lang),
                list(.default = sex)
            )
        )
    )
# # A tibble: 87 × 1
#    sex
#    <chr>
#  1 Man
#  2 none
#  3 none
#  4 Man
#  5 Woman
#  <etc>
```

#### A note on `.default`

Note that unlike `recode`, we need to provide [`case_match()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_match.html) with the `.default` parameter:

> The value used when values in `.x` aren't matched by any of the LHS inputs. If `NULL`, the default, a missing value will be used.

If this is not provided, any value not specified (e.g. `"none"`) becomes `NA`

Comment: Good idea +1. You can also use a base way `sprintf('"%s" ~ "%s"', names(lbls), lbls)` in place of `glue`.

Comment: @DarrenTsai Thanks I've updated the answer with a base R approach to injecting this (obviously with the exception of `dplyr` which was part of the question)`. I think `reformulate()` is a nice approach too.

Answer (score 3):

You can transform the named vector into a list of formulas in advance.

```r
rules <- Map(reformulate, shQuote(lbls), shQuote(names(lbls)))

# $`'Man'`
# "male" ~ "Man"
# 
# $`'Woman'`
# "female" ~ "Woman"

starwars %>%
  select( sex ) %>%
  mutate(
    sex = case_match(sex, !!!rules, .default = sex)
  )

# # A tibble: 87 × 1
#    sex  
#    <chr>
#  1 Man  
#  2 none 
#  3 none 
#  4 Man  
#  5 Woman
#  6 Man  
#  7 Woman
#  8 none 
#  9 Man  
# 10 Man  
# ℹ 77 more rows
```